# When is this matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Given the matrix 
$$A = 
 \left[
 \begin{matrix}
   2 & 2 & h & 6 \\
   0 & 4 & 2 & -2 \\
   0 & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
  \end{matrix}
  \right]
$$
find the value of $h$ so that the matrix is diagonalizable. $$$$
The  eigenvalues of $A$ are $2,2,4,4$. Now I know $\Lambda$, but have difficulty finding a proper $P$.

Comment: What are $\Lambda$ and $P$? What have you tried? Jordan form? Have you computed the kernels relative to $2$ and $4$?

Answer (score 0):

**Test for diagonalization :** Let $A$ be a linear operator on an $n$ dimensional vector space $V$. Then $A$ is diagonalizable $\iff$ both of the following holds:

- $\rho_A(x)$ splits
- For each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, $$\text{multiplicity of $\lambda$ = $n-\text{rank} (A-\lambda I)$}$$

---

Here, your case the first one holds.

So the question becomes, for what value of $h$, the matrices $$A-2I=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &2 &h&6\\0&2&2&-2\\0&0&0&2\\0&0&0&2 \end{pmatrix} \& \;A-4I=\begin{pmatrix} -2 &2 &h&6\\0&0&2&-2\\0&0&-2&2\\0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix} $$

have simultaneously  rank $2$ ?

Ans: $h=2$